# Syncing PC data with online data

Tags: python, sql-server, browser, synchronization

I have made an online website which acts as the fronted for a database into which my customers can save sales information. So each customer logs onto the online website with their own credentials and only see their own sales records. The database comes in the form of `SQL Server 2008`.

Some of these customers have a third party Windows tool on their PCs which itself acts as a fronted for a database with specific sales records. This tool is used by them for printing receipts. This tool comes with a Python interface which can be used to update the database, if the tool itself is not used. I've installed the tool on my PC and successfully added records to this tool's database by running a simple Python Script.

At the moment, customers are adding by hand sales information from my website to the tool on the PC. I would like to provide them with an automatic way of doing this. This syncing should only occur when the customer requests such a sync and indeed they have all requested that it should work so. This is to ensure that they get an opportunity to validate the information.

How might I solve this problem? Should I develop a PC application which they install on their local computer or can I do this via the browser? Either solution will need to execute Python code in order to update the database on their PC and then there are of course security issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open up [REST API's](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) for doing this.

In the current model you describe, you have a database, and user interacts with the data via a webapp. The webapp in turn has two components, the server side backend, and client facing frontend (though they may seem as one single codebase).

So currently, your architecture is something like

```
DB(1) <--> Webapp Backend(2) <--> Webapp Frontend(3)
```

And your user interacts at layer 3 to talk to data present at layer 1

Now, in your new model, the user can also access the data via a standalone desktop application. So, in this case, the PC application(4) needs to communicate with block 2 of your architecture like below

```
DB(1) <--> Webapp Backend(2) <--> Webapp Frontend(3)
                  |
                  |
            PC Desktop Application(4) <--> Local PC Database(5)
```

You will need to emulate the relationship between (2) and (3) for data access above, to (2) and (4) as well. So, you can add API support for data access at (2). The API will need to be authenticated, so that only the concerned users are able to access the data.
For the authentication, you may need to generate user access tokens, or you can validate based on user credentials. In case of access tokens, you will again need to store them at your end in the database(1) in a separate table, and expire/regenerate them periodically.

Next, you can write a small python snippet, using which, the end users of desktop application can sync data from their tool. This snippet will have to be entered in the place where you run db updates in python in layer 4. Basically, this snippet will contain code to access your API, and fetch data.

Caveats:

1. If that user fetches data using one set of access tokens, and then uses another set of credentials, gets another set of sales data, and both of them are present simultaneously in his local copy 5, then it will create a misleading data set. The situation may/may not arise according to your business case. If it does arise, you may also need to clear away all past sales data and reinitialize to the current value.
2. Another eventuality you will have to prepare for will be the size and frequency of data requests, based on which your server capacity might need to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

So in summary you have a website/sql server application. Then some of your users have a separate local database with a python front end. And you need to bridge the two applications.

You can expose your sql server database with an rest api (using whatever tech of your choice).  Then create a python app that calls that api (either via a button or automatically scheduled) and then executes the needed python code for the reporting.

Another approach would be to add that needed reporting functionality into your web app. So if you look at the functionality of what the 3rd party database and reporting provides and add that functionality into your website so there's no longer a need to use that 3rd party application at all.

Those are your two paths to go down based on on the info provided.

Comment: Thanks @daniel.nelson! Would you mind adding some more information to the second part of you answer: "Another approach would be to add that needed reporting functionality into your web app." Thanks again!